# app rejection related to background service

Tags: iphone

My app just got rejected ;-( for the following reason:

> "We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We noticed your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but does not include features that require persistent location.
>
> It would be appropriate to add features that require location updates while the app is in the background or remove the "location" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key."

I looked at my info.plist and it contained what was stated in the rejection. Now I removed location from "Required background modes" (in Xcode) and the array is now empty. Can I simply delete that key entirely? I mean, that key is not required, is it?

I also noticed something else. although it is not in the rejection. the info.plist has "Application supports iTunes file sharing" set to YES, what is that? Maybe I should remove that too, or set it to NO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now I removed location from "Required background modes" (in Xcode)
>   and the array is now empty. Can I simply delete that key entirely? I
>   mean, that key is not required, is it?

Yes, that key is optional and you can delete it

> I also noticed something else. although it is not in the rejection.
>   the info.plist has "Application supports iTunes file sharing" set to
>   YES, what is that? Maybe I should remove that too, or set it to NO.

This key set to YES enables users to add/delete files in the application's Documents folder using iTunes on their PC. If your application does not use this functionality then you should delete that key as well as that may also be a reason for rejection (actually it was exactly the reason for rejection of one of my apps few weeks ago so you can trust me here :) )

Comment: being paranoid and just want to be so sure... delete that key "Application supports iTunes file sharing", essentially says "NO", right? I am just paranoid, if the default of that is YES - in which case, deletion will be bad... so you simply deleted the ""Application supports iTunes file sharing" and your app passed right?

Comment: yes, thats's right. Although I think setting it to NO should work as well

Comment: OK I will just delete it. When I resubmit my app, should I change version to 1.1, or stay as 1.0? Do you increase version number for each submission even if the previous one was rejected?

Comment: You don't need to change version number of rejected build

Comment: @user1239040 out of random curiosity, how/why did these info.plst keys get set in the first place?

Comment: I actually have no idea, initially we had two people worked on it, and later became a solo action - me only. I simply do not remember that I added those keys unless they were there by default (???), otherwise the other guy added them at the beginning. That's why I got confused when I saw the rejection report, I did not even know those keys existed.